# Uderstanding DECODE and ENCODE in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, decode, encode

I needed to save id in such a way that would make it encrypted and so that it would take up exactly 8 characters.
I did that using the following command:

```
SELECT encode(LPAD(id,4,0),'abc')
```

This command turns an id = 1
into 0001 and then turns that into a code fe5ab21a

How do I decrypt this code?

Below is an example of a select and the result it generates

```
SELECT 0001
, DECODE(ENCODE('0001', 'abc'), 'abc')
, UNHEX(DECODE(ENCODE('0001', 'abc'), 'abc'))
, ENCODE('0001','abc')
, DECODE('fe5ab21a', 'abc')
, UNHEX(DECODE('fe5ab21a', 'abc'))
, HEX('0001')
```

The result:

```
1
30303031
0001
fe5ab21a
68d357a7005dcbe0
NULL
30303031
```

Comment: What you want to do with your code ? because "encrypted id" sound really bad for me...

Comment: I need to generate short character codes (they will have to type it by hand) for a group of users for a single use but I can't modify the structure of the database. The only unique field in the table is id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to make like a short unique key-pass that's linked to one of your ID.

**Be careful with this kind of encryption, if someone want to break it, it'll take less than a few minutes, it's really weak.** But if it's only for some obfuscation without security risk, it's ok.

**To improve a bit the security (but decrease the user experience), try to use [AES_ENCRYPT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt)**

The wrong thing with your code is that you don't force the type of input/output, here is something with the proper typing.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7cc1/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'hello'),
    (2, 'hola'),
    (3, 'bonjour')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *, ENCODE(id,'KEY') as encrypted_id from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7cc1/4/0)**:

```
| id |    name | encrypted_id |
|----|---------|--------------|
|  1 |   hello |         Vw== |
|  2 |    hola |         yw== |
|  3 | bonjour |         iA== |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * from t where id = CAST(DECODE(FROM_BASE64('yw=='),'KEY') AS CHAR(50))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7cc1/4/1)**:

```
| id | name |
|----|------|
|  2 | hola |
```